# Unexpected behavior of regex word boundaries with Unicode strings

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7, unicode

Can someone please explain this behavior of regex:

When I replace the last two characters of a Unicode string with some other Unicode character it works fine with line-boundary (`$`) at the end of string but generates unexpected results if I specify the `$` in square braces `[$]`.

Also the word boundary `\b` is giving unexpected results and surprisingly `\B`matches what `\b` is supposed to match.

```
>>> line = u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u06cc\u0670'

>>> re.sub(ur'\u06cc\u0670$', ur'\u0627', line) #works fine
u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u0627' 

>>> re.sub(ur'\u06cc\u0670[$]', ur'\u0627', line) #unexpected result
u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u06cc\u0670' 

>>> re.sub(ur'\u06cc\u0670[$]', ur'\u0627', line, re.U) #still not working
u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u06cc\u0670'

>>> re.sub(ur'\u06cc\u0670\b', ur'\u0627', line, re.U) #unexpected 
u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u06cc\u0670'

>>> re.sub(ur'\u06cc\u0670\B', ur'\u0627', line, re.U) #unexpected
u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u0627'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The signature of `re.sub` is:

   ```
   sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
   ```

   The `re.U` flag is being passed to `count`, so the `re.U` flag does nothing. Make sure you use the keyword argument like:

   ```
   re.sub(ur'\u06cc\u0670\b', u'\u0627', line, flags=re.U)
   #                                           ^~~~~~
   ```
2. `[…]` defines a character class, and `$` is not special inside the brackets. So `[$]` will just match a literal dollar sign.
3. `\b` matches the boundary between a word ("\w") and non-word ("\W", or the start/end of string), and `\B` matches anywhere that is not `\b`. Now, `\u0670` is a non-word in Unicode:

   ```
   >>> re.findall(ur'\w', line, flags=re.U)
   [u'\u0627', u'\u062f', u'\u0646', u'\u06cc']
   >>> re.findall(ur'\W', line, flags=re.U)
   [u'\u0670']
   ```

   This means the end of string after `\u0670` is *not* a word-boundary, because `\u0670` is not a word. So `\b` cannot match it, and that means `\B` will match it.

   The meaning of `\w` in Unicode is "`[0-9_]` plus whatever is [classified as alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233076/determine-if-a-unicode-character-is-alphanumeric-without-using-a-regular-express) in the Unicode character properties database".

   Characters like U+06CC (Arabic Letter Farsi Yeh) is categorized as **Letter, Other (Lo)** so it is a word, but U+0670 (Arabic Letter Superscript Alef) is categorized as **Mark, Nonspacing (Mn)** so it is *not* considered a word.

(You may check detail of Python's regex syntax in https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

---

As for the comment below, you can use a [negative look-ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) instead of a group:

```
re.sub(ur'(?:[\u06cc\u06d2]\u0670|\u0670[\u06cc\u06d2])(?!\w)', u'\u0627', line, flags=re.U)
```

Here,

- `[\u06cc\u06d2]\u0670|\u0670[\u06cc\u06d2]` is the same as your `\u06cc\u0670|\u06d2\u0670|\u0670\u06cc|\u0670\u06d2`, but with similar cases grouped together
- `(?:…)` defines a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group), so that the "\b" you want can be extracted out from the alternations
- `(?!\w)` means we match only if the next character is not a word.

The result is like:

```
>>> re.sub(u'(?:[\u06cc\u06d2]\u0670|\u0670[\u06cc\u06d2])(?!\w)', u'\u0627', line, flags=re.U)
u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u0627'
>>> re.sub(u'(?:[\u06cc\u06d2]\u0670|\u0670[\u06cc\u06d2])(?!\w)', u'\u0627', line + u'\u0646', flags=re.U)
u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u06cc\u0670\u0646'
>>> re.sub(u'(?:[\u06cc\u06d2]\u0670|\u0670[\u06cc\u06d2])(?!\w)', u'\u0627', line + u'\u061f', flags=re.U)
u'\u0627\u062f\u0646\u0627\u061f'
```

Comment: Actually I want something like `re.sub(u'\u06cc\u0670\b|\u06d2\u0670\b|\u0670\u06cc\b|\u0670\u06d2\b', u'\u0627', line, re.U)` but since `\b` wont work in this case, so I tried `re.sub(u'\u06cc\u0670(\s)|\u06d2\u0670(\s)|\u0670\u06cc(\s)|\u0670\u06d2(\s)', ur'\u0627\1', line, re.U)` but  now I don't know which group number I've to replace with `\1` or `\2` or ... . Can you please help me with this.